# How can I distinct with 2 key value in mongodb with Java maven?

Tags: java, mongodb

```
import com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.DistinctIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Projections;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Sorts;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContext;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */

/**
 *
 * @author matth
 */
public class finder {
    ArrayList<String> brands,models;
    String uri = "mongodb+srv://admin:adr@atlascluster.xcy35.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    public String CarBrandName=" ";
    public finder(String willsearch){
        

        //if equals to brand

        try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri)) {
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("AutomobileSubMaterialsSystem");
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("AutomobileParts");
            
            if("Brand".equals(willsearch)){
            brands=new ArrayList<String>();
  
            MongoCursor<String> c=collection.distinct(willsearch,String.class).iterator();
            
            while(c.hasNext()){
                brands.add(c.next());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < brands.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(brands.get(i));
                System.out.println(brands.size());
            }}
            
            //if equals to brand
            else if("Model".equals(willsearch)){
                models=new ArrayList<String>();
                AggregateIterable<Document> output=collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$match",CarBrandName)));
                for(Document dobject : output){
                    
                    System.out.println(dobject.get("Model"));
                }
                
            } 
        
        }
            
        }
           
}
```

I have database/collection/document.Documnent example:

Brand
:
"TOYOTA"
Model
:
"COROLLA"
Year
:
2022
EngineNo
:
0
PieceName
:
"roof"
NumberOfPiece
:
23

I get all distinct brand but i cannot get to Brand's Model.My last 4 hour passed with this thing.How can i make multiple filter in java any way to do it?Thanks

Comment: You may want to mask or hide the connection string if it is a real one

Comment: thank you but not important

Comment: If you want the distinct brand+model use the aggregation query with grouping.